# Package error google_map_location_picker: 4.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, package

In my app , I'm using Some packages

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
  http: ^0.13.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.3
  html: ^0.14.0+4
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.4
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
  mvc_pattern: ^7.0.0
  location: ^4.1.1
  global_configuration:
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
  flutter_html: ^1.3.0
```

And now I want to add 2 another packages :
The First one is google_map_location_picker: 4.0.0
And when I'm trying to put it on pub this error is appear

> Because google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 depends on intl
>
> > =0.16.0 <=0.16.1 and akl_beti depends on intl ^0.17.0, google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 is forbidden. So, because
> > akl_beti depends on google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving
> > failed. pub get failed (1; So, because food_delivery_app depends on
> > google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving failed.)

And the second package is intl_utils: 1.8.0
And when I'm trying to put it on pub this error is appear

> Because intl_utils ^1.7.0 depends on http ^0.12.2 and
> food_delivery_app depends on http ^0.13.0, intl_utils ^1.7.0 is
> forbidden. So, because food_delivery_app depends on intl_utils 1.8.0,
> version solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because
> food_delivery_app depends on intl_utils 1.8.0, version solving
> failed.)

So , How can I deal with this problem !

Comment: Try setting the problematic package version to `any` like so:
`google_map_location_picker: any` and `intl_utils: any`
Then, run `flutter pub get`. Lastly, go to the updated `pubspec.lock` file and find the relevant resolved package versions there.

Comment: for all packages !!!
for example :  intl:
shared_preferences:

Comment: Take a look at my updated comment

Comment: It's works thanks for your help you save my day

Answer (score 0):

The error in the pubspec indicates that the version of `google_map_location_picker` and `intl_utils` has dependencies on lower versions of other packages used.

While using the [any](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#traditional-syntax) syntax is allowed, it's not recommended as mentioned in the docs. Using the syntax can potentially set it to a broken version of the package. It's better to manually set the older versions of `google_map_location_picker` and `intl_utils` to find the version compatible with the other packages that you're using.